# Sahi on Jenkins DB error - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: linux, jenkins, sahi

Error - java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
(..)
INFO: Error in Sql Query.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUITEREPORTS (ID BIGINT IDENTITY, SUITEREPORTID VARCHAR(255), SUITENAME VARCHAR(2000), SUITEPATH VARCHAR(2000), STARTTIME TIMESTAMP, ENDTIME TIMESTAMP, STATUS VARCHAR(255), TOTALCOUNT INT, PASSEDCOUNT INT, FAILEDCOUNT INT, TIMETAKEN INT, BROWSERTYPE VARCHAR(255))

At one moment (possible because free space was missing) sahi builds on jenkins stop working. When I open log DB I got text - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!

And in console log:

```
[java] Nov 21, 2017 1:37:22 PM in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB createTables
 [java] INFO: version=2017-05-09 20:45:45
 [java] Nov 21, 2017 1:37:22 PM in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB createTables
 [java] INFO: Updating tables structures.
 [java] java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.PooledDBClient.getConnection(PooledDBClient.java:31)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.DBClient.execute(DBClient.java:66)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.executeSQL(SahiDB.java:162)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.createTables(SahiDB.java:98)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.<clinit>(SahiDB.java:32)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.f.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [java] Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
 [java]     ... 8 more
 [java] Nov 21, 2017 1:37:54 PM in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB createTables
 [java] INFO: -----------------------------------------------
 [java] Nov 21, 2017 1:37:54 PM in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB createTables
 [java] INFO: Error in Sql Query.
 [java] CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUITEREPORTS (ID BIGINT IDENTITY, SUITEREPORTID VARCHAR(255), SUITENAME VARCHAR(2000), SUITEPATH VARCHAR(2000), STARTTIME TIMESTAMP, ENDTIME TIMESTAMP, STATUS VARCHAR(255), TOTALCOUNT INT, PASSEDCOUNT INT, FAILEDCOUNT INT, TIMETAKEN INT, BROWSERTYPE VARCHAR(255))
 [java] exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.PooledDBClient.getConnection(PooledDBClient.java:31)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.DBClient.execute(DBClient.java:66)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.executeSQL(SahiDB.java:162)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.createTables(SahiDB.java:98)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.<clinit>(SahiDB.java:32)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.f.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [java] Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
 [java]     ... 8 more
 [java] 
 [java] Nov 21, 2017 1:37:54 PM in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB createTables
 [java] INFO: -----------------------------------------------
 [java] java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.PooledDBClient.getConnection(PooledDBClient.java:31)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.plugin.DBClient.execute(DBClient.java:66)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.datastore.SahiDB.executeSQL(SahiDB.java:162)
 [java]     at net.sf.sahi.test.SuiteSummary.init(SuiteSummary.java:104)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.distributed.DSuiteRunner.execute(DSuiteRunner.java:72)
 [java]     at in.co.sahi.command.Master$1.run(Master.java:117)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [java] Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
 [java]     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
 [java]     ... 8 more
```

Where can be problem? What can I do to fix?

Comment: it's built-in database. I had at this moment two separate DB going down. And only way to get up was - replacing DB files with blank new ones

Answer (score 0):

can you please tell me that which database you are using with Sahi.

Make sure that you added the correct JDBC URL for your database in Sahi properties.

Comment: it's built-in database. I had at this moment two separate DB going down. And only way to get up was - replacing DB files with blank new ones